# When converting to a numpy array, how can eliminate the single quotation marks? (python3)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

[image]

i want this

```
array([[2600, 11749, 9], [976, 16, 2, ...],...)
```

But I don't know why single quotes are printed. What should I do?

Comment: How are you creating your array? It looks like you had a list containing the string representations of a bunch of lists, where you wanted to have a list of lists.

Comment: @Blckknght The element type in the column is str. However, it consists only of integers. I want to make a list of lists, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Those quotes aren't frivolous decorations.  They tell you what the frame actually contains - strings, not lists.  My guess is that you loaded this frame from a `csv` file.  You need to look at the file, and if possible the original data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each row in `X_train` is a string rather than a list, so I think you need to convert those strings to lists. I think this should do it:

```
X_train = pd.Series([[int(x) for x in string.strip('[]').split(',')] for string in X_train.tolist()])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that numpy arrays of different lengths have been entered into the pandas series.

It seems that numpy arrays of different lengths have been entered into the pandas series.

try this

```
X_train.values
```

or

```
list(map(np.array, x_train))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `X_train` is a `pandas` dataframe.  It's hard to tell from a frame display what a column such as yours contains - is it really arrays?  The `np.array(X_train)`, tells us no, it contains strings that look like arrays.  `X_train.to_numpy()` is the preferred way of extracting an array from a frame, but I think the result will be the same.

My guess, from past SO questions, is that originally you had a frame with arrays in a column.  Then you saved it as `csv`, and reloaded it. Because `csv` is inherently a 2d format, `pandas` has to write strings, rather than arrays.  That's what you got.

Look at the source `csv`.

While it is possible to convert those strings to arrays (provided they don't contain `...`), it isn't a trivial.  Many previous SO have suggested ways, but I'll let others find the relevant duplicates.

Even if you succeed in converting the strings to arrays, the frame will still contain arrays that vary in length, which means the resulting array will still be  `object` dtype, an array containing arrays of varying length.  It will not a 2d numeric dtype array.

The name `X_train` suggests you want to use this data for some form of machine learning.  Most, if not all, of those methods expect data that's consistent in size.  The arrays should have shapes like `[batch, samples, features]`.  They can't be "ragged".

Make a frame :

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame([None,None,None],columns=['one'])
In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
    one
0  None
1  None
2  None
In [29]: df['one'] = [np.ones(5),np.arange(4),np.zeros(9)]
In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
                                             one
0                      [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1                                   [0, 1, 2, 3]
2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

A ragged array:

```
In [31]: df.to_numpy()
Out[31]: 
array([[array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])],
       [array([0, 1, 2, 3])],
       [array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]], dtype=object)
```

Make a csv and back:

```
In [32]: df.to_csv('test')
In [33]: df1 = pd.read_csv('test')
In [34]: df1
Out[34]: 
   Unnamed: 0                           one
0           0              [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
1           1                     [0 1 2 3]
2           2  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Notice how the display is the same as [30].  But the array is like yours:

```
In [35]: df1.to_numpy()
Out[35]: 
array([[0, '[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]'],
       [1, '[0 1 2 3]'],
       [2, '[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]']], dtype=object)
```

The `csv` looks the same as the frame - no quotes.  But the csv reader cannot parse the `[]` parts.  It just splits the test on comma.

```
In [36]: cat test
,one
0,[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
1,[0 1 2 3]
2,[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

But wait, [34] doesn't have commas.  That's because the source frame had lists, not arrays.

```
In [37]: df['one'] = [np.ones(5).tolist(),np.arange(4).tolist(),np.zeros(9).toli
    ...: st()]
In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
                                             one
0                      [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1                                   [0, 1, 2, 3]
2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
In [39]: df.to_numpy()
Out[39]: 
array([[list([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])],
       [list([0, 1, 2, 3])],
       [list([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])]],
      dtype=object)
In [40]: df.to_csv('test')
In [41]: cat test
,one
0,"[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]"
1,"[0, 1, 2, 3]"
2,"[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]"
In [42]: df1 = pd.read_csv('test')
In [43]: df1
Out[43]: 
   Unnamed: 0                                            one
0           0                      [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1           1                                   [0, 1, 2, 3]
2           2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
In [44]: df1.to_numpy()
Out[44]: 
array([[0, '[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]'],
       [1, '[0, 1, 2, 3]'],
       [2, '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]']], dtype=object)
```

Converting strings like that to lists is easy - just use `eval` on each.